# Python3 загрузка файлов на Selectel

Tags: python, файлы, http, requests

Пишу загрузчик файлов на Selectel. Упрощённо код выглядит примерно так:

```
filename = 'example_watermarked.jpg'

headers['Content-Length'] = str(os.path.getsize(filename))

files = {
    'file' : open(filename, 'rb')
}

url = auth['url'] + 'images/python_uploader/' + filename

response = requests.put(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

Получается следующая вещь - исходный файл 38158 байт. Файл на Селектеле - 38317 байт. Файл, естественно, не открывается. Откуда берутся "лишние" 159 байт? Что я делаю не так?

P.S. `os.path.getsize(filename)` возвращает 38158, т.е. корректный размер.

P.P.S. Через Postman попробовал, точно так же у меня загрузился битый файл. Только теперь он 38355 байт.

**Update:**
В начало добавился такой вот блок:

```
--de966cbba4ab406da3dd088e63bd9c7f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; 
filename="example_watermarked.jpg"
```

В конец - вот такой:

```
--de966cbba4ab406da3dd088e63bd9c7f--
```

Остальное - бинарные данные.

Comment: Попробуйте не указывать Content-Length -- requests сам его установит, к тому же, размер файла на диске может отличаться от реального его размера

Comment: @gil9red я пробовал изначально, то же самое. Тогда уже я явно указал

Comment: Если можно, попробовать через браузер повторить операцию и посмотреть что отправляется. А пример есть? т.е. ссылку на которую можно было отправить файл и проверить самому что работает

Comment: @gil9red нуууу... Теоретически на своём сайте я могу написать роут, который примет файл, и посмотреть что придёт. Однако вангую, что Селектел не косячит, ибо с соседнего компа коллега через PHP загружает нормально

Comment: Ну не знаю, пальцем в небо: 1. а через post можно файлы отправить? 2. а какая версия питона/requests? 3. Попробуйте включить логирование requests и посмотреть запрос: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/fc39378cf1b3b0fa3a067166a0e54423d36a3b98/requests_example/debug_logging__requests.py

Comment: @gil9red я извиняюсь, Вы были правы. Через Postman попробовал, точно так-же у меня загрузился битый файл. Добавлю эту информацию в вопрос

Comment: Не пробовали официальную библиотеку для работы с виртуальным приватным облаком Selectel использовать? https://habrahabr.ru/company/selectel/blog/336066/

Comment: @insolor пытался. по взаимодействию с облачным хранилищем через неё не нашёл инфы в доках, и в целях экономии времени решил ручками попробовать. Благо дело несложное. Казалось

Comment: @КапитанФлинт, вот вроде бы нашел доки по API именно облачного хранилища: https://kb.selectel.ru/22058988.html

Comment: @insolor ну да, всё верно :) именно этим я и руководствовался, когда писал свой код

Comment: @КапитанФлинт, пробовали скачивать и сравнивать файлы?

Comment: @КапитанФлинт, я не пробовал их апи пользоваться, но контейнеры есть, возможно вечером посмотрю в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: @insolor пробовал сравнивать как бинарники, ничего не понял :)

Comment: @КапитанФлинт, я имею в виду посмотреть как именно отличается файл: добавился блок в начало, в конец, или вообще данные не совпадают?

Comment: @insolor добавил в топик блоки, которые приклеиваются к файлу

Comment: @КапитанФлинт, ну что могу сказать, у меня тот же результат (добавляет лишнее в начало и конец файла). Попробуйте в техподдержку написать.

Comment: @insolor да, писал сегодня утром. Опубликовал их ответ здесь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написал в техподдержку, вот что они мне ответили:

> Попробуйте, пожалуйста, передавать в запросе не сам объект а его тело. Пример кода:

```
import requests

headers = {"X-Auth-User": "0000", "X-Auth-Key": "xxxxxxxxx"}

r = requests.get("https://auth.selcdn.ru/", headers=headers)

assert r.status_code is 204

auth_token = r.headers.get("X-Auth-Token")
storage_url = r.headers.get("X-Storage-Url")


filename = "sample-pic-4.jpg"
data = open(filename, "rb").read()

r = requests.put(storage_url + "testcontainer/testupload/" + filename, data=data, headers={"X-Auth-Token": auth_token})
r.raise_for_status()
```

я переписал свой код с учётом их поправки, всё заработало

Comment: То есть, если захотим загрузить файл в несколько гигабайт в контейнер, то сначала нужно в любом случае грузить в память, а потом уже в контейнер.

Comment: @insolor к счастью, такой задачи пока не стоит. Если возникнет - напишу им снова :)

Answer (score 1):

Все сходится к тому, что Selectel API неправильно обрабатывает файлы, отправленные методом POST с [`Content-Type: multipart/form-data`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data), [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578).

См. тут например: [Генерация HTTP запросов, Метод POST](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/HTTP-POST.php#part_3), пример запроса из этой статьи:

```
POST http://www.site.ru/postnews.html HTTP/1.0\r\n 
Host: www.site.ru\r\n 
Referer: http://www.site.ru/news.html\r\n 
Cookie: income=1\r\n 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=1BEF0A57BE110FD467A\r\n
Content-Length: 491\r\n
\r\n
--1BEF0A57BE110FD467A\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="news_header"\r\n
\r\n
Пример новости\r\n
--1BEF0A57BE110FD467A\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="news_file"; filename="news.txt"\r\n
Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n
\r\n
А вот такая новость, которая лежит в файле news.txt\r\n
--1BEF0A57BE110FD467A--\r\n
```

В вашем вопросе `de966cbba4ab406da3dd088e63bd9c7f` - это boundary, т.е. метка, обозначающая границы блока данных. При приеме начальная метка, служебные данные после нее до двойного переноса строки и конечная метка должны обрезаться.

Отсутствие поддержки данного варианта запроса, насколько я понимаю, приведет к тому, что перед отправкой файл придется полностью грузить в память, и если этот файл "весит" несколько гигабайт, то это уже становится проблемой.